# Table of contents in Beamer R Studio

Tags: beamer, r

i'am trying to generate an beamer presentation but i can't add an Ouline of my document: this is my code:

```
---
title: 'PEC-3 Gestión Económico-Financiera: Casos de Negocio. El sector de la distribución
  de cine en España; estrategia de futuro'
author: "Víctor Manuel Conte Pozo"
date: "22/1/2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
  beamer_presentation: default
  slide_level: 2
  slidy_presentation: default
  toc: yes
---


\tableofcontents

## PEC3-Gestión Económico-Financiera, Enunciado


## Introducción
Dadas las 3 opciones, mediante el análisis de cada una de las 3, definieremos definir los pros y contras de cada una y acabar seleccionando una de ellas dos procesos $P$.  

- $P_1$: Análisis de indicadores
```

Comment: Can you try with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826534/2777074

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826534 it seems that you activate the toc with the following syntax:

```
---
title: 'PEC-3 Gestión Económico-Financiera: Casos de Negocio. El sector de la distribución
  de cine en España; estrategia de futuro'
author: "Víctor Manuel Conte Pozo"
date: "22/1/2019"
output:
  beamer_presentation: 
    toc: true
---

## PEC3-Gestión Económico-Financiera, Enunciado 

## Introducción
Dadas las 3 opciones, mediante el análisis de cada una de las 3, definieremos definir los pros y contras de cada una y acabar seleccionando una de ellas dos procesos $P$.  

- $P_1$: Análisis de indicadores
```

Comment: Untested, if anyone could confirm or falsify the above answer, I'd be glad to hear!

Answer (score 0):

First, your header is broken: How can different output formats be `default` at the same time? Also, the indentation is not correct. See [user36296's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471325/table-of-contents-in-beamer-r-studio/472307#472307) how to correct it.

As an alternative to [user36296's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471325/table-of-contents-in-beamer-r-studio/472307#472307), to manually add a table of contents using `\tableofcontents`, one first needs to start a slide.

Also, in order to obtain a non-empty table of contents, there need to be some section headings...

The following code will actually produce two tables of contents: an automatic one (due to `toc: yes`) and a manual one (due to `\tableofcontents`).

```
---
title: 'PEC-3 Gestión Económico-Financiera: Casos de Negocio. El sector de la distribución
  de cine en España; estrategia de futuro'
author: "Víctor Manuel Conte Pozo"
date: "22/1/2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
  beamer_presentation: default
  slide_level: 2
  slidy_presentation: default
  toc: yes
---

## Outline

\tableofcontents

# Section 1

## PEC3-Gestión Económico-Financiera, Enunciado

# Section 2

## Introducción
Dadas las 3 opciones, mediante el análisis de cada una de las 3, definieremos definir los pros y contras de cada una y acabar seleccionando una de ellas dos procesos $P$.  

- $P_1$: Análisis de indicadores
```